# Transforming Hibernate Entity to clean POJO for serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, pojo

I'm still new to using ORM stuff in Java, and here is one question I seem to be stuck on:

I have a large number of Hibernate Entities and want to query for them on the server (works fine) then serialise them (using ObjectOuputStream) and send them to a client.

If I deserialize them on the client there is still a large number of Hibernate / javax.persistence dependencies.

Is it possible to transform my entities to POJOs with no dependency on hibernate at all somehow?

Thanks!

EDIT:
To clear thing up, I am using annotations, which is probably silly. I will need to redefine all classes to be annotation-free, then they should be standard POJOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just have to fall back to XML configuration as opposed to convenient annotations. Hibernate has its [`hbm`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) files from the very beginning, with JPA you use `orm.xml`.

Every can be expressed with XML, annotations are only syntactic sugar. This way your entities will be absolutely free of Hibernate/`javax.persistence` references.

See also: [JPA: Should I clean up my entity classes using orm.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874064)

P.S.: Keep in mind that serializing your domain model (JPA/Hibernate entities) will prove to be a pain soon once you start refactoring your domain model. Even when you control both sides. Really, really consider DTOs.

Comment: Thank you! My entities actually got sent around using protostuff and not plain serialization, but networking was a teammate's component. I'm busy writing up issues I encountered using Hibernate Spatial and not being able to serialize/deserialize was one of them.